# Can't call method in EJB bean

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0, ejb

I'm getting crazy over an error I'm currently experiencing.

> 14:45:08,492 ERROR
>   [BusinessControllerInterceptor] object
>   is not an instance of declaring class
>   [ERRID: 0845]
>       org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException:
>   AOP configuration seems to be invalid:
>   tried calling method [public abstract
>   at.package.List
>   at.package.Search.search(at.package.Employee)]
>   on target [searchTarget]; nested
>   exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   object is not an instance of declaring
>   class

The searchTarget is an EJB bean and implements the interface with which it is called, so the method exists.

I don't know where else to look for mistakes. Maybe you have some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. In my application context I've written

```
    <property name="target">
        <value>searchTarget</value>
    </property>
```

instead of

```
    <property name="targetName">
        <value>searchTarget</value>
    </property>
```

Since the property `target` is expecting an object, it thought of my target as a string.